# Getting connection timeout while connecting to URL to get the IP details

Tags: java, geolocation, ip

Following is my code which is trying to connect to different URL's which provides details about the IP address.

```
    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception, URISyntaxException {

    String ip = "2.51.255.200";
    // http://whois.net/ip-address-lookup/
    // http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&IpAddress=162.115.44.104
    // http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/162.115.44.104
    // http://freegeoip.net/csv/137.188.83.252
    URL url = new URL("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/162.115.44.104");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.3 Safari/537.31");
    connection.connect();

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (status != 200) {
        return;
    }

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        //this API call will return something like:

       // "2.51.255.200","AE","United Arab Emirates","03","Dubai","Dubai","","x-coord","y-coord","",""
        // you can extract whatever you want from it
        System.out.println(line);
    }       
}
```

When I am running this code it is giving me connection timeout exception as below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.vzw.velite.services.TestURL.main(TestURL.java:22)
```

I am not sure what is missing here, I am connected to internet and I am running this code in my Eclipse Juno IDE.

Comment: Can you make the same connection from a web browser? Is the web browser configured to use a proxy?

Comment: When I am firing the same URL in browser I am able to get the details, Browser is not currently using proxy. and I am connected with a wired connection